# Как получить правильный position после getFilter в SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, filter

Помогите найти решение. Проблема в том, что после фильтрации SimpleAdapter с помощью getFilter, при клике по элементу выдаются новые позиции 0,1,2. А мне необходимо чтобы после фильтрации позиции элементов остались прежними.

**UPD:**

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

            // Фильтрация
            jsonAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            //jsonAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

UPD2:

В общем у меня есть json файл, который я редактирую при клике.

```
[{
  "name": "name_value",
  "category": "category_value",
  "image": "image_value"     
},
{
  "name": "name_value_2",
  "category": "category_value_2",
  "image": "image_value_2"     
}]
```

Без фильтрации всё происходит хорошо. Нажимаю на элемент в списке, редактирую его, сохраняю, и редактируется выбранный JSONObject. Т.е. выбрал name_value_2 и отредактировал конкретно его.

Текущие элементы по клику получаю так:

```
final HashMap<String, Object> itemHashMap =
                    (HashMap<String, Object>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

final String name = String.valueOf(itemHashMap.get("name"));
final String category = String.valueOf(itemHashMap.get("category"));
String image = String.valueOf(itemHashMap.get("image"));
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда список отфильтрован (например ищу name_value_2), данные отображаются от name_value_2. Но чтобы мне отредактировать именно JSONObject требуется index элемента **final JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(index);**. А index у отфильтрованного списка начинается с 0. А мне нужно, чтобы показывало корректный индекс.

Данные добавляю так:

```
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray keys = jsonobject.names();
                    map = new HashMap<>();

                    for (int l = 0; l < keys.length(); ++l) {

                        String key = keys.getString(l); 
                        String value = jsonobject.getString(key); 

                        map.put(key, value);

                    }
```

Comment: для чего вам это нужно?

Comment: Чтобы взять данные из JSONObject мне нужна позиция элемента.JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(pos). Но когда я фильтрую список, то у меня берется первый объект из json а нужно тот который я выбрал из отфильтрованного списка

Comment: Привидите код вашей фильтрации)

Comment: Добавил к вопросу

Comment: а что в методе getFilter

Comment: Ничего. Это стандартный метод от SimpleAdapter

Comment: фильтрация происходит же?

Comment: фильтрация происходит, но когда я выбираю из отфильтрованного списка первую позицию, то ее индекс 0, а мне нужен индекс этого элемента который был до фильтрации

Comment: У вас проблема в следующем?

Вы сделали фильтрацию,потом например кликнули на отфильтрованный item,а он вам дал данные неактуальные из -того что происходит получение данных по неактуальной позиции?

Comment: По хорошему,вам нужно избавиться от JSONObject

Comment: Это плохой тон программирования,вам в адаптер нужно передавать массив элементов который вам нужно достать из JSONObject

Comment: У вас  есть понимание как это сделать?

Comment: Так я в адаптер и передаю массив элементов из JSONObject. Далее при клике я уже беру данные из адаптера, а не из JSONObject. Но мне в конечном итоге нужно удалять и редактировать JSONObject. А чтобы вставить новые данные в JSONObject мне нужна его позиция в списке. Я программирую не так давно, поэтому можете объяснить мне, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Зачем вы редактируете JSONObject ? Привидите код вашего апдатера.

Comment: Как вариант можно добавить в каждый элемент оригинальную позицию, когда вы готовите данные для адаптера. При выборе берём элемент из адаптера по новой позиции, достаём из него оригинальную и работаем. Если не понятно - добавьте код где вы заполняете коллекцию для адаптера и где вы обрабатываете клик по элементу

Comment: Добавьте просто к вашему Pojo классу :.  Implements Serializeble

Comment: @woesss добавил код к вопросу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно добавить в каждый элемент оригинальную позицию, когда вы готовите данные для адаптера. При выборе берём элемент из адаптера по новой позиции, достаём из него оригинальную и работаем:

```
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray keys = jsonobject.names();
map = new HashMap<>();

for (int l = 0; l < keys.length(); ++l) {
    String key = keys.getString(l); 
    String value = jsonobject.getString(key); 
    map.put(key, value);
}

// заносим позицию объекта в элемент списка
map.put("position", i);
```

---

```
final HashMap<String, Object> itemHashMap =
                (HashMap<String, Object>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

final String name = String.valueOf(itemHashMap.get("name"));
final String category = String.valueOf(itemHashMap.get("category"));
String image = String.valueOf(itemHashMap.get("image"));

int origPos = (Integer) itemHashMap.get("position");

JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(origPos);
```

P.S. Можно и сам json-объект засунуть в мап элемента - вместо позиции будете забирать сразу объект, хотя фильтр по нему тоже будет искать - лучше всё-таки индекс заносить.

Answer (score 0):

Как все должно происходить.

1. Создали адаптер
2. Передали данные
3. Показали данные
4. Далее вводим слово по которому будет фильтровать
5. Делаем фильтрацию ( как я понял у вас фильтруется)
6. Далее нажимаем на элемент адаптера и получаем актуальные данные.
7. Работает с полученными данными при клике.

Comment: Добавил весь необходимый код к моему вопросу

Comment: зачем редактировать JSONObject

Comment: Дело в том, что первая моя программа, получает данные из json файла. А в этой программе мне нужно редактировать его